# apache regex : getting "Missing operand to closure" when using lookahead

Tags: regex, apache

I am using apache regex for the following lookaheads regular expression: `logs: (?=.*?WARN)(.*)` 
and I get `org.apache.regexp.RESyntaxException: Syntax error: Missing operand to closure`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a lookahead in the middle of the regexp?

Comment: Why not just `logs: .*?WARN(.*)` ?

Comment: I noted that it doesn't really matter, even the simplest lookahead regexp fails, for instance I get the exception here as well:
`String regexp = "logs: (?=WARN)";  
RE regularExpression = new RE(regexp, RE.MATCH_MULTILINE);`

Comment: In bash can you type `pcretest -C` out of curiosity?

Comment: I really don't know. I'm using Java on windows OS